# Uniformly bounded sequence {X_i} of independent random variables series converges or diverges depending on bejavior of variance?

Tags: pr.probability

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a uniformly bounded sequence of independent random variables. Does $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i-E[X_i]$ converges or diverges, depending on whether $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sigma_i^{2}$ converges or diverges?

I have looked everywhere for a proof with little success. Can someone provide a reference or a proof? Thank you.

Comment: There's a whole book "Almost sure convergence", by Stout, where this must (almost) surely be one of the first results.

Comment: [Kolmogorov's three-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) is your friend, if you ask for almost sure convergence.